# SeeTest (Mobile automation) support for serenity

Tags: serenity-bdd, seetest

we are trying to implement serenity to test mobile application using SeeTest automation tool. can anyone guide what will be best way. currently we are able to connect to the device with the help of wrappedSeeTestDriver.once the execution completes results are generated but screen shots are not captured. also operations like sendText("{ENTER}"); also not working. Any suggestions idea will be great help.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve BDD with SeeTest, you can use SpecFlow with C#. Below are high level Steps:

1. Write acceptance criteria of your test case in a FeatureFile as scenarios in Gherkin language.
2. Write StepDefination - where you write underlying implementation for each line in feature file in C#.
3. When you build your project, all the tests in your feature file will be displayed TestExplorer.
4. Right click and execute any test you want.
5. SeeTest will generate the HTML report, screenshots, logs    and other outputs in TestResults folder of your project.

**sendText("{ENTER}");**:
The sendText({Enter}) (or also the 'BKSP') is basically try to use the enter from the android keyboard, and it is a possibility that this application or specific activity on the application developed different.

If you are using seeTestAutomation and open the application in the reflection and spotify to the right place when you testing the enter, try to press manual in the the computer's keyboard 'enter', is it working?

Also please try with adb command  (run command in seeTest) "adb shell input keyevent 66" (66 is  the keycode for enter) and if this won't work - it means that the enter command is not implemented this view of the application.